# How to pass device UUID in CoreBluetooth framework for Client to reconnect later

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral

I just wrote a simple app where I scan and connect to peripheral (which is also an IOS device). However the CBPeripheral object I get back from ConnectPeripheral function does not have the device UUID and it's always null. Now I am trying to understand where do I set it so that it gets passed.
Here is what I am doing.

To advertise my service I am doing

```
NSDictionary *advertisingDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: services forKey:CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey]
[manager startAdvertising:advertisingDicts];
```

(From the framework I understand that I cannot pass the device UUID in the advertising packet. Correct me if I am wrong here)

My client scan for the service and gets into the function

```
centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
```

And as expected the peripheral.uuid is null. If I call connectPeripheral on this peripheral it works fine too. I am not sure how it understands which device to connect when the uuid is null. Also what would I need to do If I want to reconnect later. How do I fill this uuid?

Comment: IOS 6 is still under NDA discuss this on Apple's developer forum.

Comment: Thanks I have posted at https://devforums.apple.com/thread/164622?tstart=0. Hopefully someone will answer

Answer (score 1):

It has a work around. You can pass it instead of the local name of the device like this:

```
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : *the UUID*}];
```

And in the other device in the didDiscoverPeripheral function you can get it like this:

```
[advertisementData objectForKey:@"kCBAdvDataLocalName"]
```